# Is it possible to access a String inside an Array, inside an Array in swift?

Tags: arrays, string, swift

Is it possible to access a string inside an array that is inside another array? - Swift

for instance:

```
    var a = 1
    var b = 2

    var maleDogs = ["Fido","Thor"]
    var femaleDogs = ["Linn","Eva"]
    var dogs = [maleDogs,femaleDogs]
```

And then do something like

```
dogs[a][b]
```

In this instance, I wanted to get "Thor" as an output, but it calls an error. (Inside playground)

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: @b3rge: Your code is completely correct, but note that Swift array indices are *zero-based*, so accessing index 2 will cause an out-of-bounds exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is completely correct, but note that Swift array indices are *zero-based*, so accessing index 2 causes an "Array index out of range" exception.
You can see the error message if you open the "Assistant Editor" for the Playground file
(View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor).

What you probably wanted is

```
var a = 0
var b = 1

var maleDogs = ["Fido","Thor"]
var femaleDogs = ["Linn","Eva"]
var dogs = [maleDogs,femaleDogs]

dogs[a][b]  // Thor
```